# Windows : print environment variables with wildcard?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have these environment variables : `OUTPUT_FOR_TEST1`, `OUTPUT_FOR_TEST2`, `OUTPUT_FOR_TEST3` etc.
Also these variables are dynamically constructed in a batch script basically by appending `OUTPUT_FOR_` with `TEST1`, `TEST2`, `TEST3` because I don't know ahead what are `TEST1`, `TEST2`, `TEST3`.

At the end of my batch file, I want to echo these variables. But because these variables are dynamically created, how can I print them all? Can I use a wild card like : `echo %OUTPUT_FOR_*%` , I don't think so. Any suggestions?

I know power shell can do it, but I prefer to stick to batch only solution if there one exists.

Also to make clear : I want to print just values not the whole environment variable description like OUTPUT_FOR_TEST1=TEST1_RESULT

May be I can use `set OUTPUT_FOR_ >> temp.txt`, parse `temp.txt` to get values, but that is more work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set output_for
```

this will print all variables which name starts with `output_for`.
Then you can use (from command line):

```
for /f "tokens=2* delims==" %# in ('set output_for') do @echo %#
```

from batch:

```
for /f "tokens=2* delims==" %%# in ('set output_for') do @echo %%#
```

or

```
(for /f "tokens=2* delims==" %%# in ('set output_for') do @echo %%#)>>output
```

Comment: set output_for will print `OUTPUT_FOR_TEST1=TEST1_RESULT`, I want just values that is why I wanted to use echo %OUTPUT_FOR_...

Comment: Thanks, will it work if I have '=' in the environment variable value?

Comment: @svasa - yes it will .`2*` means take everything after first `=`

Comment: anyway thanks for the answer. this is simple enough and suits my purpose.

Comment: @svasa: "ok, why # instead of something like `%%a`?" Answer: because it is more confusing this way **`;)`** (unless npocmaka have a better explanation)

Comment: @Aacini - of course I have !  :-)  . When you have some nested `FORs`  letter tokens are especially valuable , so they must be spared and when you have to use a single token I prefer **#** or **$** to prevent overwritings, though this is rather a habit .

Comment: IMHO if this problem would appear in a specific solution (that use more than 52 tokens in nested for's), _then_ you may use non-standard characters _and_ explain the reason; otherwise, you may just confuse beginners...